# abort() is not working in dependent UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mern, redux-toolkit

I am trying to optimize my react code by fixing any memory leaks. I am using [createAsyncThunk canceling-while-running](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#canceling-while-running) to cancel requests, if my component unmounts.

I have three reducers inside two `useEffect` hooks. One dispatches when the component mounts and the other two dispatches when the response from the first dispatched reducer arrives.

Below is my code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const promise = dispatch(bookDetails(bookId))
  return () => promise.abort()
}, [])

// this is triggered when the response from the dispatched "bookDetails" reducer arrives
// and get stored in the "book" variable as shown in dependency array
useEffect(() => {
  let promise1, promise2
  if (book._id !== undefined) {
    promise1 = dispatch(getComments(book._id))
    promise2 = dispatch(relatedBooks({ genre: book.genre }))
  }
  return () => {
    promise1.abort() // BookDetails.jsx:58:1
    promise2.abort()
  }
}, [book])
```

When the component mounts the second `useEffect` gives me an error, given below:

```
BookDetails.jsx:58 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'abort')
    at BookDetails.jsx:58:1
    at safelyCallDestroy (react-dom.development.js:22932:1)
    at commitHookEffectListUnmount (react-dom.development.js:23100:1)
    at invokePassiveEffectUnmountInDEV (react-dom.development.js:25207:1)
    at invokeEffectsInDev (react-dom.development.js:27351:1)
    at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (react-dom.development.js:27324:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27056:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26076:1)
    at flushSyncCallbacks (react-dom.development.js:12042:1)
```

I tried few things but it didn't workout for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `promise1` and `promise2` is assigned within the condition `book._id !== undefined` , it has the possibility of not being assigned. Simple quick fix is checking a condition when invoking `.abort()`. Something like `promise?.abort()` or `typeof promise?.abort === 'function' && promise.abort()`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a condition on dispatching the asynchronous actions in the second `useEffect` hook. This means that `promise1` and `promise2` are potentially undefined. Only return the cleanup function if the actions are dispatched.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (book._id && book.genre) {
    const promise1 = dispatch(getComments(book._id));
    const promise2 = dispatch(relatedBooks({ genre: book.genre }));

    return () => {
      promise1.abort();
      promise2.abort();
    };
  }
}, [book]);
```